# Why Does GCC Throw Errors About Unspecified Options?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

When I run the following command from a makefile on 64-bit Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.0 using GCC 4.2.3:

```
gcc -c -ansi -pedantic -O0 -fPIC -I. -I.. -Iheader_files/include "source_file.c"
```

I get the following error:

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-lang-c"
```

Superficially, the problem is that "-lang-c" is no longer a valid option on newer versions of GCC.  However, the deeper question is: Why does GCC receive a "-lang-c" option that wasn't in the original command?

Additional background:

- The current installation doesn't have any GCC "specs" files that I can find
- Running "gcc -dumpspecs" produces a long list of defaults, but "-lang-c" isn't among them.
- "-lang-c" does not appear to be in any environment variables that I know of that influence GCC.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Mark Biesiada

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your `gcc` driver program is the same version as your installed GCC.

Add the `-v` option to your compile command to check the versions and where the options are coming from.

Comment: Also `locate gcc` and `locate cc1` will help you find other versions of the compiler that may be getting in the way.